# How to solve maximum call stack size exceeded jQuery JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to do Ajax form submission. In this, I am using REST API for form submission. But when I am clicking on submit button, I am getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. I do not know why I am getting this error as I am not calling any function recursively. Below is my JavaScript Code:

```
    $('#btn_addproduct').click(function(){
            var prductname = document.getElementById('productname').value;
            var productcode = document.getElementById('productcode').value;
            var taxcategory = document.getElementById('taxcategory').value;
            var descriptivename = document.getElementById('descriptivename').value;
            var category = document.getElementById('categorydd').value;
            var subcategory = document.getElementById('subcategorydd').value;
            var tag = document.getElementById('tagsdropdown').value;
            var skucode = document.getElementById('skucode').value;
            var hsccode = document.getElementById('hsccode').value;
            var bonuscarriage = document.getElementById('bonuscarriage').value;
            var baserating = document.getElementById('baseratingdd');
            var publish = document.getElementById('publishdd').value;
            var productimg = document.getElementById('imagepath').value;
            var url = "../<%=AkApiUrl.addproduct%>";
            $.post(url,{
                prductname : prductname,
                productcode : productcode,
                taxcategory : taxcategory,
                descriptivename : descriptivename,
                category : category,
                subcategory : subcategory,
                tag : tag,
                skucode : skucode,
                hsccode : hsccode,
                bonuscarriage : bonuscarriage,
                baserating : baserating,
                publish : publish,
                productimg : productimg,
            },function(data, status) {
                if (data.status == "OK") {
                    if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                        alert("Product Added Successfully");
                    }else {
                        var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            });
        });
```

This is my controller code to set data into the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = AkApiUrl.addproduct, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces ={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}) public ResponseEntity<?> addproduct(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("category") String category, @RequestParam("prductname") String prductname, @RequestParam("taxcategory") String taxcategory, @RequestParam("tag") String tag, @RequestParam("descriptivename") String descriptivename, @RequestParam("skucode") String skucode,  
@RequestParam("subcategory") String subcategory, @RequestParam("hsccode") String hsccode, 
@RequestParam("bonuscarriage") String bonuscarriage, @RequestParam("baserating") int baserating, 
@RequestParam("publish") String publish, @RequestParam("productcode") String productcode, @RequestParam("productimg") String productimg) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        try {
                User loginuser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
                Product product = new Product();
                Long categoryid = Long.parseLong(category);
                Category cid = categoryDao.findByCategoryid(categoryid);
                Long tagid = Long.parseLong(tag);
                Tag tid = tagDao.findByTagid(tagid);
                Long subcategoryid = Long.parseLong(subcategory);
                Subcategory sid = subcategoryDao.findBySubcategoryid(subcategoryid);
                product.setPrductname(prductname);
                product.setProductcode(productcode);
                product.setTaxcategory(taxcategory);
                product.setDescriptivename(descriptivename);
                product.setSkucode(skucode);
                product.setHsccode(hsccode);
                product.setCategory(cid);
                product.setTag(tid);
                product.setSubcategory(sid);
                float carriage = Float.parseFloat(bonuscarriage);
                product.setBonuscarriage(carriage);
                product.setBaserating(baserating);
                product.setPublish(publish);
                product.setProductimg(productimg);
                product.setCreatedby(loginuser);
                Product newproduct = productdao.save(product);
                if (newproduct != null) {
                    CustomResponse.setResponse(newproduct);
                    CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                    CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
                    CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
            CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I trigger a click on the button but I get the below error on my console.[image: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Comment: A photo of your screen?  You do know your keyboard as a [prtsc] button which copies the screen to the clipboard?  Or, in windows 10 , winkey-shift-s to start snip&sketch?

Comment: I've updated that screenshot. Now it will be more clear. I am getting 200 HTTP status. But the data did not save inside the database.